# Who are these biologists?

Tags: history, species-identification

[image: biologists]

I know the third one in the front row is James Watson.

Does anyone recognize the others?

Comment: This has no relevance in biology

Comment: Should we put the `species-identification` tag?

Comment: While not being an ideal question (where and when was the photo taken? why do you want to know?), I still think these kinds of questions should be allowed here. We have the *history* tag, which is relevant for this Q (history of biology), the Q has a definite answer, and BioSE should be as good a place as any to ask about the identification of prominent biologists.

Comment: I agree with fileunderwater. I vote to reopen

Comment: Without the context of *where* (geographical location + setting) and *when* this photo was taken - I vote to leave closed on the basis of being **unclear** what you are asking -slash - **homework** (no effort whatsoever / poorly researched)

Comment: Sitting next to Jim Watson is another Nobel Laureate, Wally Gilbert (on the right in the photo) but actually on Watson's left.

Comment: Plus there is a History of Science and Mathematics SE site, so wouldn't it be best to keep this question there?

Answer (score 14):

Front row, left to right; [Victor McKusick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_A._McKusick), [Maurice Wilkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Wilkins), James Watson, [Walter Gilbert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Gilbert) and [John Kendrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Kendrew).

Comment: Great! +1 Do you know where/when the picture was taken? Seems to have a high density of Nobel laureates.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to find any context for this photo, I just recognized the scientists. It appears to be a relatively formal meeting and most of them are molecular biologists/geneticists, but I'm not sure why they would be holding papers if it was anything but an experiment (though I can't imagine what experiment they would attend that involved molecular biology) my only other guess would be perhaps some sort of a conference because they all seem to be taking notes and looking in the same direction. Again, I'm not sure. I apologize for not being able to find anything on it.